# ExternalLogin not hiting when call to Facebook/Google+

Tags: c#, facebook-login, identity, google-signin, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm making an integration with Facebook and Google to log with this application in mine, but when i click in the button supose to login with Facebook or Google i'm gotting 302 response, ckeched this responde on [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

[image]

It's redirect to Login withou hit ExternalLogin.

This is my Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddFacebook(fOptions => {
        fOptions.AppId = "myAppId";
        fOptions.AppSecret = "myAppSecret";
        fOptions.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; })
    .AddGoogle(gOptions => {
        gOptions.ClientId = "myClintId";
        gOptions.ClientSecret = "myClientSecret;
        gOptions.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; })
    .AddCookie();
```

I'm using Identity to create users too.

My ExternalLogin on AccountController:

```
public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
{
    var props = new AuthenticationProperties()
    {
        RedirectUri = Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback"),
        Items =
        {
            { "returnUrl", returnUrl },
            { "scheme", provider },
        }
    };

    return Challenge(props, provider);
}
```

And my buttons to login with respective external:

```
<div class="col_full text-center nomargin" style="margin-bottom: 5px !important">
    <a asp-action="ExternalLogin" asp-route-provider="Facebook" asp-route-returnUrl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" class="button button-rounded nomargin si-facebook si-colored" style="width: 100%" type="button">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook
    </a>
</div>

<div class="col_full text-center">
    <a asp-action="ExternalLogin" asp-route-provider="Google" asp-route-returnUrl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" type="button" class="button button-rounded nomargin si-google si-colored" style="width: 100%">
        <i class="fa fa-google"></i> Google
    </a>
</div>
```

But when i click in this "button" it't not hiting ExternalLogin in controller and getting back to Login with this URL:

> https://localhost:5000/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FExternalLogin%3Fprovider%3DFacebook

I'm using .NET Core 2.1

some idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appers a problem of authorization to access this route, your AccountContoller use an Attribute [Authorize]?. If yes, the Authorize Attribute force any request of any action of this controller will be redirected to Login.

To solve it, you can put [Authorize] only in actions that user need be authenticated or using [AllowAnonymous] in ExternalLogin Action.